An error occurred: 'AzureOpenAI' object has no attribute 'Completion' in RAG using OpenAI keys and Langchain

I am fetching my embeddings from Mongo Atlas
Converting the query to embeddings using text-embedding-adaa002 api key
Performing Similarity check
Introduced GPT api keys and azure endpoint

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY_GPT"] = "xxx"
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT_GPT"] = "https://xxx.openai.azure.com/"
mongodb_connection_string = "xxx"

client = MongoClient(mongodb_connection_string)
db = client['langchain-test']
collection = db['xx']

openai.api_key_gpt = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY_GPT")
azure_openai_endpoint_gpt = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT_GPT")

openai_gpt_client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=openai.api_key_gpt,
    api_version="2024-02-15-preview",
    azure_endpoint=azure_openai_endpoint_gpt
)

def generate_embeddings(text, model="text-embedding-ada-002"):
    response = openai_client.embeddings.create(input=[text], model=model)
    return response.data[0].embedding


def generate_response(context):
    prompt = f"Based on the following context, answer the question:\n\n{context}"
    response = openai_gpt_client.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1102-westus", prompt=prompt, max_tokens=150)
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

#Fetch embedding from Atlas
pdf_chunks_db = fetch_embeddings()

#Generate Embedding of the query text
all_embeddings = [chunk["embedding"] for chunk in pdf_chunks_db]
for chunk in pdf_chunks_db:
    chunk["embedding"] = generate_embeddings(chunk["text"])

#Give top 5 similar chunks from db
question = "Your question here"
results = answer_question(question, pdf_chunks_db, all_embeddings)

#Combine all 5 similar searches
combined_context = "\n".join([result[0]['text'] for result in results])

#Response using gpt api keys
response = generate_response(combined_context)
print(response)

I am getting an error in generate_response function- An error occurred: 'AzureOpenAI' object has no attribute 'Completion'

I assume you imported the AzureOpenAI client from Langchain. In Langchain, call the model with openai_gpt_client.invoke("hi").

See langchain AzureOpenAI docs

I think your code has bug.
You are instantiating the client
openai_gpt_client = AzureOpenAI

After that you are doing embedding with incorrect client
response = openai_client.embeddings.create(input=[text], model=model)

I think you should be fine, if you call openai_gpt_client.embeddings
